# PHP Sending Value With the name Attribute Depends upon No of Rows

Tags: php, html, post, methods

[Check this Image 1_A is the name attribute made from a combination of cid(courseId) and Section Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNiHN.png)
Is there any Way that I can get these name in $_POST method and I don't want to use an array in the name attribute. I use echo in name attribute So, the
name of each course and section should be different depending on the number of rows matched coming from the database.
HERE IS THE CODE SNIPPET.

```
                while($course1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                  echo '<div id="'.$course1['sectionID'].'-course-outline" class="tab-pane fade">

                     <h1>'.$course1['title'].' ('.$course1['SectionName'].') - Upload Course Outline</h1>
                    <div class="row">
                    <form class="outline-form" action="outline_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-primary">
                   Choose Files <input type="file" name="'.$course1['cid'].'_'.$course1['SectionName'].'" class="file-class" multiple>
                </span>
                                </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input  class="btn btn-info upload-button" type="Submit" value="Upload" >
                        </div>

                    </form>
                    </div>

                  </div>';      
              }
```

Comment: A little unclear what you are asking. Are you talking about echo $_POST["whateverName"];

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php The exctract() function will take the elements of an array and make local variables named after the keys of each array element. Can be very dangerous though.

Comment: @icewine No, For example name come from database and cid means courseid = 1 and SectionName ='A'
so name would be like that 
name="1_A" it means all the data  of the attribute is generic.
I just want to get that "1_A" or anything like "1_B" "1_C" in $_POST.
and i don't know which courseID and sectionName comes from database.
So the more accurate is $_POST['unknown combination of sectionName and course id from database']

Comment: The manner where your code is, Do you know that you'll have more than one `form` tag depending by number of database data ? So you'll have more than one form... and like this, you'll need JavaScript

Comment: @Goms Yes, I have to upload the course outline of different sections of different course so in this case, i have 2 subjects
with 1 have 2 sections
and the second one has 1 section.
so total 3 forms generate.

Comment: Now, what do you want exactly ? Be clear please !

Comment: @Goms 
 For example name come from database and cid means courseid = 1 and SectionName ='A' so name would be like that name="1_A" it means all the data of the name attribute is generic. I just want to get that "1_A" or anything like "1_B" "1_C" in $_POST like $_POST['1_A']. and i don't know which courseID (cid) and sectionName comes from database. So the more accurate is $_POST['unknown combination of sectionName and course id from database']

Answer (score 0):

I am still not quite sure what you want to do, but if you are trying to get all of the post data and do something with any possible names that match "courseId_SectionName" than you could do this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

   //echo $key." -- > ".$value;

   if (strpos($key, "_") !== false){
      //echo "do something with the code here";
      echo $key; // this is the "name" matching if it has "_" in it somewhere

      echo $value; // this is the value of the $key.

   }

}
```

Comment: In a simple words, the name attribute is totally unknown to me how can I get it in PHP through $_POST['name value']

Comment: Like I used above, without knowing the name it searches all post names and returns only those matching "something_something"

Comment: all the names are generated as something_something.
like i said before:
i have to upload the course outline of different sections of different course so in this case, i have 2 subjects with 1 have 2 sections and the second one has 1 section. so total 3 forms generate.
and each form input name be like:
1_C, 1_A, 2_B ,8_H etc....

I have to insert the name of that form from which file is uploaded from all three forms (as these forms could be more than three in future). so how i could i get in $_POST['1_A'] so i know that this data comes from the form of courseid with 1 and sectioName is A.

Answer (score 0):

If I well undestand you, this can help you
Firstly, it's `$_FILES` who will have informations, not `$_POST`

```
foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file)
{
   list($cours_id, $cours_name) = explode('_', $name);
   //$cours_id and $cours_name have respetively cours id and cours name
   $filename = $cours.$cours_name.'.'.pathinfo($file['name'])['extension'];
   /*
   You can save your data both in database and filesystem

   $db->exec("INSERT INTO coursoutline SET filename = '$filename'");
   move_uploaded_file($filename, __DIR__.'/path/to/save');

   */
}
```

Comment: I need to insert the file of a name and courseID in the table of courseoutline(cid int, filename varchar(20));
how can I use `$cours_id, $cours_name`  in `outline_upload.php`  as you wrote?. as it can only be used in my main file not in action file though.

Comment: Of course, you'll use it in action file `outline_upload.php` in your case. And you'll insert in database one after other.